# Is there a word that means "the person who is to receive a report"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, er-ee

Is there a word that means "the person who is to receive a report"?

I'm looking for the equivalent of *assignee* with the difference that it would describe the person who is to be reported to.

Example:

> - The assigner assigned the assignment to the assignee.
> - The reporter reported the report to the [reportee?].

Comment: The "recipient".

Comment: Usually the person who receives the report is the person who commissions the report-  The *commissioner*

Comment: Thanks Peter and Jim, when I saw "recipient" I chuckled because it's clearly the right word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Peter Shor notes in the comments, the most appropriate word is *recipient*:

> recipient — somebody or something that receives something

Answer (score 0):

I think I might, in such circumstances, use 'reportee'.

You probably won't find it in the dictionary, but as an old hand I adjudge it to be within the scope of the creative licence that English affords. (And I say that as one who abhors excessive licence). The problem with 'recipient' is that for clarity's sake you may have to say 'the report's recipient' which is a bit of a mouthful.

I await the voting in a state of suspended animation!

Comment: Problems arise where the report is about a person; he's the reportee.

Comment: @Andrew Leach How do you know that? The word is not in the OED. I would have described him as the 'subject of the report'.

Comment: [Patients of an action get *-ee*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71371/beneficiaries-of-an-action-ending-with-the-ee-suffix)

Comment: @WS2 I would agree with AndrewLeach, my first thought was maybe 'reportee' would work, followed by dismissing said thought due to confusion.  I would probably assume reportee to refer to the subject of the report if there were one.  Additionally, if John were reporting to someone, John would be the reportee, not the person being reported to.

Comment: @AndrewLeach If a 'reportee' can be the subject of a report, then why not call the person who is to receive the report the 'addressee'?

Answer (score 0):

The "customer", the "boss", the "addressee".